# Filtering a table created from a database

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a table of announcements being created from a database.

I am trying to filter this table into categories based on the 'type' column of the database.

The database table has a column which holds the 'type' of announcement. I want to have tabs across the top of my table which display each of these announcements based on type.

eg, Meeting tab should display all announcements of type meeting. Forecast tab should contain all announcements of type forecast.

I have hardly any experience in Javascript or Jquery and cant find a solution anywhere that is close to what I am after. I dont want a drop down filter or a search box.

HTML show.html.erb

```
<section id="announcements">
<h2>Recent Announcements</h2>
  <ul id="filter">  
    <li class="current"><a href="#">All</a></li>    
    <li><a href="#">Meeting</a></li>  
    <li><a href="#">Forcast</a></li>   
  </ul> 
<%= render "markets/announcements/table" %>
```

HTML _table.html.erb

```
<% announcements ||= @announcements %>
<% title ||= nil %>

<section id="announcements" class="screen table-screen">
  <% if title %>
    <h2><%= title %></h2>
  <% end %>
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>Title</th>
        <th class="sort-column">Date</th>
        <th>Type</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <%= render :partial => "markets/announcements/announcement", :collection => announcements, :as => :announcement, :locals => { :display_instrument_code => display_instrument_code } %>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</section>
```

HTML _announcement.html.erb

```
<tr>
  <td><%= link_to(announcement.title.truncate(50), path_for_announcements(announcement)) %></td>
  <td class="date-cell"><%= format_time(announcement.time, :format => :announcement) %></td>
  <td class="announcement_type"><%= announcement.type %></td>
</tr>
```

Below is my current Javascript and CSS. It displays 'All' fine but does not filter the other tabs.

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {  
    $('ul#filter a').click(function() {  
        $(this).css('outline','none');  
        $('ul#filter .current').removeClass('current');  
        $(this).parent().addClass('current');  

        var filterVal = $(this).text().toLowerCase().replace(' ','-');  

        if(filterVal == 'all') {  
            $('table#announcement_table tr.hidden').fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');  
        } else {  
            $('table#announcement_table tr').each(function() {  
                if(!$(this).hasClass(filterVal)) {  
                    $(this).fadeOut('normal').addClass('hidden');  
                } else {  
                    $(this).fadeIn('slow').removeClass('hidden');  
                }  
            });  
        }  

        return false;  
    });  
});
```

CSS

```
ul#filter {   
    float: left;   
    font-size: 16px;   
    list-style: none;   
    margin-left: 0;   
    width: 100%;  
}  
ul#filter li {   
    border-right: 1px solid #dedede;  
    float: left;  
    line-height: 16px;  
    margin-right: 10px;  
    padding-right: 10px;  
}
ul#filter li:last-child { border-right: none; margin-right: 0; padding-right: 0; }  
ul#filter a { color: #999; text-decoration: none; }  
ul#filter li.current a, ul#filter a:hover { text-decoration: underline; }  
ul#filter li.current a { color: #333; font-weight: bold; }
```

Thanks in advance for all your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oh man, take it easy on yourself and use the [datatables](http://datatables.net/) jquery plugin!

Follow instructions to use the [jquery-datatables-rails](https://github.com/rweng/jquery-datatables-rails) gem.

For a great tutorial on using the ajax loading paginated feature check out Ryan Bates' excellent [screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/340-datatables?view=asciicast)

Just to give you a taste of how easy it is to work with this plugin... generate your desired table with the appropriate tags including `<thead>` and `<tbody>`

Then put something like this in your script:

```
var oTable = $('#your_tables_id').dataTable({
    "sDom": "<'row-fluid'<'span6'l><'span6'f>r>t<'row-fluid'<'span6'i><'span6'p>>",
    "sPaginationType": "bootstrap",
    "aaSorting": [[ 5, "asc" ]]
});
```

The above code will create a twitter bootstrap styled table with the fifth column being the default sort in ascending order.